# Joosy tutorial ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, joosy

I was going through the [Joosy Guide](http://guides.joosy.ws/guides/blog/rails-preparations.html) but at the end of "Rails Preparation" section instead of the landing page, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mixin grid-core-span is missing argument $gridColumnWidth.
  (in /Users/scribe/Code/joosy-blog/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)):
    10:       };
    11:     </script>
    12: 
    13:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    14:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    15:   </head>
    16: 
  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:1
  app/views/layouts/blog.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_blog_html_erb___1369399347943123030_70192156915780'
  app/controllers/blog_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

As far as I can tell I my project matches the instructions, any ideas as to what I messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `sass` gem got some update. https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails/issues/24

Answer (score 1):

The error you get has nothing to do with Joosy. It comes from SCSS – you use incorrect styles mixin (incorrect arguments to be exact). If you did copy that style from guide, please provide me with a direct link, I'll make corrections. Otherwise it may be just your typo :).

Comment: Below is the tutorial I followed:
http://guides.joosy.ws/guides/blog/rails-preparations.html
With the sass copied from [link] (https://raw.github.com/gist/2759363/b9c2e3296d5a696494636e017043ab64b3233c5e/application.css.scss)
'@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';

body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}'

Comment: Sorry, better formatted code
`@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';

body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}`